# Facebook graph api keyerror 'Next'

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to scrape facebook data with script from following link. But I always get following error scanning 2000 statuses. Please, guide me what is the error. Thank you.

> Error>>> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "posts.py", line
>   191, in 
>       scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)   File "posts.py", line 181, in scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus
>       statuses['paging']['next'])) KeyError: 'next'

Script Link >> https://nocodewebscraping.com/facebook-scraper/

Script >>

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time



page_id = raw_input("Please Paste Public Page Name:")



access_token = raw_input("Please Paste Your Access Token:")

def request_until_succeed(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    success = False
    while success is False:
        try: 
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                success = True
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            time.sleep(5)

            print "Error for URL %s: %s" % (url, datetime.datetime.now())
            print "Retrying."

    return response.read()


def unicode_normalize(text):
    return text.translate({ 0x2018:0x27, 0x2019:0x27, 0x201C:0x22, 0x201D:0x22,
                            0xa0:0x20 }).encode('utf-8')

def getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, num_statuses):


    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6"
    node = "/%s/posts" % page_id 
    fields = "/?fields=message,link,permalink_url,created_time,type,name,id," + \
            "comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions" + \
            ".limit(0).summary(true)"
    parameters = "&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (num_statuses, access_token)
    url = base + node + fields + parameters


    data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))

    return data

def getReactionsForStatus(status_id, access_token):



    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6"
    node = "/%s" % status_id
    reactions = "/?fields=" \
            "reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(like)" \
            ",reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(love)" \
            ",reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(wow)" \
            ",reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(haha)" \
            ",reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(sad)" \
            ",reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(angry)"
    parameters = "&access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + reactions + parameters


    data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))

    return data


def processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, access_token):



    status_id = status['id']
    status_message = '' if 'message' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['message'])
    link_name = '' if 'name' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['name'])
    status_type = status['type']
    status_link = '' if 'link' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['link'])
    status_permalink_url = '' if 'permalink_url' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['permalink_url'])


    status_published = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            status['created_time'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
    status_published = status_published + \
            datetime.timedelta(hours=-5) 
    status_published = status_published.strftime(
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 



    num_reactions = 0 if 'reactions' not in status else \
            status['reactions']['summary']['total_count']
    num_comments = 0 if 'comments' not in status else \
            status['comments']['summary']['total_count']
    num_shares = 0 if 'shares' not in status else status['shares']['count']



    reactions = getReactionsForStatus(status_id, access_token) if \
            status_published > '2016-02-24 00:00:00' else {}

    num_likes = 0 if 'like' not in reactions else \
            reactions['like']['summary']['total_count']



    num_likes = num_reactions if status_published < '2016-02-24 00:00:00' \
            else num_likes

    def get_num_total_reactions(reaction_type, reactions):
        if reaction_type not in reactions:
            return 0
        else:
            return reactions[reaction_type]['summary']['total_count']

    num_loves = get_num_total_reactions('love', reactions)
    num_wows = get_num_total_reactions('wow', reactions)
    num_hahas = get_num_total_reactions('haha', reactions)
    num_sads = get_num_total_reactions('sad', reactions)
    num_angrys = get_num_total_reactions('angry', reactions)



    return (status_id, status_message, link_name, status_type, status_link, status_permalink_url,
            status_published, num_reactions, num_comments, num_shares,
            num_likes, num_loves, num_wows, num_hahas, num_sads, num_angrys)

def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
    with open('%s_facebook_statuses.csv' % page_id, 'wb') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file)
        w.writerow(["status_id", "status_message", "link_name", "status_type",
                    "status_link", "permalink_url", "status_published", "num_reactions", 
                    "num_comments", "num_shares", "num_likes", "num_loves", 
                    "num_wows", "num_hahas", "num_sads", "num_angrys"])

        has_next_page = True
        num_processed = 0   
        scrape_starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

        print "Scraping %s Facebook Page: %s\n" % (page_id, scrape_starttime)

        statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, 100)

        while has_next_page:
            for status in statuses['data']:


                if 'reactions' in status:
                    w.writerow(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status,
                        access_token))


                num_processed += 1
                if num_processed % 100 == 0:
                    print "%s Statuses Processed: %s" % \
                        (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now())


            if 'paging' in statuses.keys():
                statuses = json.loads(request_until_succeed(
                                        statuses['paging']['next']))
            else:
                has_next_page = False


        print "\nDone!\n%s Statuses Processed in %s" % \
                (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
```

Comment: You should post your actual code, it'll make it easier to help. From a high view, the issue is because `status['paging']` doesn't have a 'next' Key. Which probably means you reached the last page.

Comment: I edited with actual code and I would like to know how can I correct 'Next' key error when reached last page to print out data in csv format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change this condition `if 'paging' in statuses.keys():` with

```
if 'paging' in statuses.keys() and 'next' in statuses['paging'] and statuses['paging']['next']:
```